# Summoning an item in 1.9 with motion

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I put

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b,Motion:[0.0,0.8,0.0]}}
```

in a command block, it summons the diamond with `Count:1b` but it doesn't follow the `Motion` Tag. Does anyone know how to get the `Motion` Tag working?

Answer (score 4):

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Motion:[0.0,0.8,0.0],Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b,}}
```

That should work. You were using it in *Item* tag, but it should be on the entity itself.