# How do I summon something with velocity in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I summon something with velocity in Minecraft? I tried searching it on google and click the links I can find. When I tried them, it didn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summoning an item in 1.9 with motion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269003/summoning-an-item-in-1-9-with-motion)