# Summoning projectile with motion

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying this for two days and cant get anything. I just want a trident to move. I used motion tags, direction tags, power tags, and it just spawns and falls down, this is what I have so far and it doesn't work:

```
/summon minecraft:trident ~ ~3 ~ {Motion:[0,5,-10],Direction:[0,5,-10],Power:[0,5,-10]}
```

How can I go about getting my trident to move somewhere else?

Comment: [This question has already been asked here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380876/how-to-summon-something-with-velocity-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

Very common problem-

```
/summon minecraft:trident ~ ~3 ~ {Motion:[0.0,1.0,-10.0]}
```

u have to do .0